# Which is better option? @Async with or without ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, threadpool

What is the use of defining manual thread executor inside the @Async annotation in spring? When we don't define executor, the @Async is working better.

Use case:
I have created a manual thread pool with max pool size is 50. If we pass 200 requests it process only up to 50 requests. But if we don't define manual thread executor for @Async, it is working fine.

`@Async("messageQueueExecutor")` - Stops after max pool size

`@Async` - works fine

#### ThreadPoolConfig.java

```
package config;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:threadpool-config.yml")
public class ThreadPoolConfig {

    /* Message Queue Thread Pool */
    /* start */
    @Value("${task.execution.pool.message-queue.core-size}")
    private int mqCorePoolSize;
    @Value("${task.execution.pool.message-queue.max-size}")
    private int mqMaxPoolSize;
    @Value("${task.execution.pool.message-queue.queue-capacity}")
    private int mqQueueCapacity;
    @Value("${task.execution.pool.message-queue.keep-alive}")
    private int mqKeepAliveSeconds;
    @Value("${task.execution.pool.message-queue.allow-core-thread-timeout}")
    private boolean mqAllowCoreThreadTimeOut;
    @Value("${task.execution.pool.message-queue.name}")
    private String mqThreadName;

    @Bean("messageQueueExecutor")
    public Executor messageQueueExecutor() {
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor(mqMaxPoolSize, mqMaxPoolSize, mqQueueCapacity, mqKeepAliveSeconds, mqAllowCoreThreadTimeOut, mqThreadName);
    }
    /* end */

    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maxPoolSize, 
            int queueCapacity, int keepAliveSeconds, 
            boolean allowCoreThreadTimeOut, String threadName) {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(queueCapacity);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setKeepAliveSeconds(keepAliveSeconds);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(allowCoreThreadTimeOut);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix(threadName);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler((runnable, executor) -> {
            executor.execute(runnable);
        });
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }   

}
```

#### application.properties

```
task.execution.pool.message-queue.max-size: 42
task.execution.pool.message-queue.allow-core-thread-timeout: true
task.execution.pool.message-queue.core-size: 7
task.execution.pool.message-queue.keep-alive: 60
task.execution.pool.message-queue.queue-capacity: 11
task.execution.pool.message-queue.name: messagequeue-threadpool-
```

Comment: Show us the bean configuration of `manualThreadExecutor`.

Comment: Without it it will create an unbounded number of threads instead of reusing a pool, which can lead to all sorts of error. Also it will only process 50 concurrently everything else will be placed in a queue and as soon as a thread is ready it will be processed.

Comment: I have updated my question with thread pool config.

Answer (score 1):

Manual Thread Executor, to have a better control, specific to your application configuration.

In specific, to the number of threads, since you have configured, max pool size of 50, the executor WILL NOT allow more than 50. Thats crystal clear!

However, the apart from your configuration for max pool size, this is also limited by the System processor.