# How to create a different ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, threadpoolexecutor

I am now using `@EnableAsync` and `@Async` annotation to use multithreaded in Spring Boot. I have service A(fast) and service B(slow).

How can I set different pool for them? So when there are lots of calls for B, the application can still handle service A in a different pool from B.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ServiceExecutorConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(30);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(40);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(10);
        taskExecutor.initialize();
        return taskExecutor;

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this might help you: [How to use multiple threadPoolExecutor for Async Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776483/how-to-use-multiple-threadpoolexecutor-for-async-spring)

Comment: The following question also has the configuration https://stackoverflow.com/q/56286235/7458887

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, you can define your thread pool executor and use them as a configure them as beans like this -

```
@Configuration
public class ThreadConfig {
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor executorA() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("default_task_executor_thread");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    } 

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor executorB() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("executor-B");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

After that, you can specify your executor on method level like this -

```
@Async("executorA")
public void methodWithVoidReturnType(String s) {
    .....
}

@Async("executorA")
public Future<String> methodWithSomeReturnType() { 
   ...
   try {
      Thread.sleep(5000);
       return new AsyncResult<String>("hello world !!!!");
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      ...
   }

   return null;
}
```

Comment: In this way how can I set the AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler?

Answer (score 6):

```
@Bean(name = "threadPoolExecutor")
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(7);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(42);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(11);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("threadPoolExecutor-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}

@Bean(name = "ConcurrentTaskExecutor")
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor2 () {
    return new ConcurrentTaskExecutor(
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3));
}

@Override
@Async("threadPoolExecutor")
public void createUserWithThreadPoolExecutor(){
    System.out.println("Currently Executing thread name - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    System.out.println("User created with thread pool executor");
}

@Override
@Async("ConcurrentTaskExecutor")
public void createUserWithConcurrentExecutor(){
    System.out.println("Currently Executing thread name - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    System.out.println("User created with concurrent task executor");
}
```